# Choosing a communication library for a distributed application

Tags: tcp, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, multicast

I started develop a distributed application and we have a big dilemma! We need a communication library easy to use and with the following features:

- reliable communication
- groups/channels
- unicast
- multicast
- auto-discover
- security
- supported by multiple programming languages
- supported on multiple operating systems
- supporting geographical distribution is a plus

A few words about this application

The main idea behind this distributed project is to have a frontend, a backend (processing application) and hundreds of agents which will collect data from some datacenters. The communication between agents and backend should be a simple as possible, we should have possibility to push configuration or to pull real time data from agents. A minimal security of the transport between agents and backend is required. Also we should have possibility to add/delete new nodes in backend cluster live. If the number of nodes of backend cluster is changing, the agents should redistribute their load (probably this should be made by backend through filtering). Usually the messages (between agents and backend) will not exceed 1500 bytes, but from time to time we should be able to send large packets (a good fragmentation management is a must).

What we found until now:

- jGroups
- Spread
- openpgm
- zeromq
- Hazelcast

If you have experience in developing clustering applications, please let me know which of the above frameworks are suitable for my project? Also, if you know other free libraries which are suitable for my project and are not listed above please let me know!

Comment: For more details see my blog post here http://www.randombugs.com/cluster/choosing-communication-library-distributed-application.html  , but please comment here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Have a look on Akka http://akka.io/ , it has most of the features your are looking for.

Comment: Akka doesn't have C++ bindings.

Comment: Back to 2012, there is only few solution to choose. Nowadays, there are Kafka, RocketMQ, RabbitMQ and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend ZeroMQ. Also have a look at Heartbeat, the cluster messaging layer in Linux-HA. http://linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat

Comment: Do you have any experience with zmq? Please explain why you "highly recommend".

Comment: I evaluated it for a cluster application we were building and it looked very promising: easy to use, great performance... in the end we went with a hackish solution of using a PostgreSQL database to publish messages, mainly because we already knew that pg could be trusted, and to remove complexity (it was already used for data storage, point to point communication was not needed). Using an sql database for messaging just feels wrong and I wish we had used zmq instead.

Comment: Is not really what I expected, but until now is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Message_Queue_Evaluation_Notes) is the most recent and comprehensive evaluation I have seen on the topic. Also check out [hurricane](http://icheishvili.github.com/hurricane/)

Comment: Is very comprehensive for messages queues, but I need a communication library with C++/Java/Python support. Until now only 0mq know that even if is not a real "Message Queue".

Answer (score -1):

I have no direct experience working in this area so please forgive me if my suggestion is somewhat stupid.

I have encountered a free library that seems like it could be useful to you, it is produced by Google and is called [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html).  It is specifically designed to be used in language-neutral, platform-neutral environments and in the production of communications protocols.

There are also numerous [third party RPC implementations](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns#RPC_Implementations) that work with the Protocol Buffers format.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Protocol Buffers is wonderful when you want to write your own  network protocols, but not in this case. I want a free library not to write my own protocol :). Thanks for suggestion.